# CurveyCorners/CSS3PIE Alternatives and Glitches

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3pie

I am attempting to have rounded corners (preferably using `border-radius` css, but I can entertain another option at this point). 
I've tried CSS3PIE, but it caused issues with in IE8 with jquery and there were display problems where items were displaced several pixels from their true positions.
I then tried CurveyCorners, but it stopped my ability to change css on hover (using the jquery `$(this).removeClass("nohover");$(this).addClass("hover");` )

Are there alternatives?

Comment: I think we're gonna need to see some markup.

Comment: when using css3pie, did the elements that were out of position return to their proper position after you hovered or clicked on it? I am currently building a site that used css3pie but I found that it slows down the site too much so now IE8 is degrading to square corners.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle I'm not wanting help with the code, unless you know of something off-hand. I just want alternatives. The markup for the curvey corners issue is literally what I posted. take a div and put that in the mouseover with the appropriate css and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Huangism I had that issue too. There were several CSS3PIE issues. It worked fine with simple layouts, but anything slightly complicated or nested got a little off.

Comment: My site is responsive so it was having all kinds of issues. It was just much easier and faster to let IE8 degrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through this quite a few times now and I always end up at the same place. Here's what my experience's tell me.

- Use CSS border-radius for rounded corners in all modern browsers
- Let older browsers degrade gracefully
- Use LESS CSS (for the mixins): http://lesscss.org/
- Use LESS CSS mixins to easily code border-radius w/o having to personally input specific - versions of border-radius for different browsers. http://lesselements.com/
- Use less.js to compile while you develop (or use codekit).

Here's a great example of a less elements border-radius mixin:

```
#some_div {
  .border-radius(5px, 0, 0, 5px);
}
```

Or you can just code the different versions of border-radius by hand :)

Final though: One of the main issues with trying to force IE8 to have rounded corners with Javascript is that generally you're asking the browser to do a lot of extra work. Machines running IE8 are often institutional machines without a lot of extra horsepower to spare. This can make for an end user experience far worse than a degraded CSS page.

Comment: Ended up having to degrade to a non-rounded style. I tried several methods, but with the intense interactivity and on-the-fly page changes, it just had too many bugs.

Comment: I was hoping you'd prove me wrong :) But I've never had any luck with this on high traffic production sites either. Cheers!